# Read webpage using URL in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, url

I have a wi-fi module connected to my arduino uno. There is server setup using it. The Wi-Fi is sending data(`<p>Start</p>`) on IP address 192.168.4.1. Now if I connect my PC to the hotspot created using Wi-Fi module and open browser and go to address http://192.168.4.1/ then text 'Start' is displayed.
I have to take that text in MATLAB. I found this page.
http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/example--reading-a-url.html?searchHighlight=url
This is the code I am using apparently it works on very few websites like mathworks.com and snapdeal.com.
Here is  the code I am using.

```
clear all;
clc;
url = java.net.URL(... 
'http://192.168.4.1')
is = openStream(url);
isr = java.io.InputStreamReader(is);
br = java.io.BufferedReader(isr);
p1 = java.lang.String('<p>');
p2 = java.lang.String('</p>');
s = readLine(br);
while ~(s.startsWith(p1))
s = readLine(br);
end
s
```

Here is the output..

```
url =
http://192.168.4.1
Error using test (line 5)
Java exception occurred:
java.io.IOException: Invalid
Http response
at
sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown
Source)
at
java.net.URL.openStream(Unknown
Source).
```

Please tell me the possible solution.

Answer (score 1):

are you sure your webpage is setup correctly? Can you view the source code and verify it actually says `<p>Start</p>` To do this in in chrome or IE navigate to the page and press `ctrl+u` to view source

You also might need to add more than just your paragraph to your web page. I'm not sure what exactly your sever is doing but here is a good example http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype.asp

I think when you view the source code to REALLY work it needs to look mroe like this

```
{!DOCTYPE html}
{html}
{p}Start{/p}
{/html}
```

I replaced all the `<>` with `{}` otherwise stack overflow interprets it and displays it as a regular paragraph

Comment: Yes, It says `<p>Start</p>`.

Comment: Hey andrew, I changed the code the wifi now sends `<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><p>Start</p></body></html>` instead of just `<p>Start</p>`. But it still shows same output.

Comment: I was hoping that would solve your problem. Does it still give the same error?

Comment: well the problem is live 5 `is = openStream(url);` You mentioned if you navigate to http://192.168.4.1/ it works. maybe enter the same exact url in matlab `url = java.net.URL(
'http://192.168.4.1/')` notice the forward slash ` / ` at the end of the url

Comment: No, I tried with the forward slash at the end but it gives the same error.